# Passing variables into command line arguments

Tags: rust

I am trying to pass a variable as a part of a bash command in my Rust program.

```
let speed_output = 70;
Command::new("nvidia-settings")
        .arg("-a")
        .arg("GPUTargetFanSpeed[fan:0]=speed_output")
        .spawn()
        .expect("nvidia-settings command failed to execute");
```

The program compiles correctly but my variable `speed_output` isn't passed to the bash shell. I would like to know how to pass variables from the Rust environment directly into the argument.

Comment: `format!("GPUTargetFanSpeed[fan:0]={speed_output}")`

Comment: This is not a bash command, since you’re not invoking bash at all; you’re spawning the process directly.